# MySQL Update Not Working With WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This statement fails to update the record.

```
UPDATE account SET accountPassword='newpassword' WHERE accountEmail='name@email.com'
```

There IS a record with accountEmail of name@email.com.

It works WITHOUT the WHERE clause.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: 'There IS a record with accountEmail of ' - nothing wrong with the update query so this statement is incorrect..try trimming accountEmail

Comment: Tried trimming and lowering. Same result, no match.  If I remove the WHERE clause it works.

Comment: I doubt if we can help you here, either the row does not exist (have you tested with a select and the same where clause?), or it contains non printing characters (you can search for how to detect these) but we cannot ask you to expose emails so that we can have a look.

Comment: I have tested with a SELECT. Works fine.  Could it be the collation or something?

Comment: Good thinking - what collations are your  table and column,

Comment: I have tried utf8-unicode-ci and utf8-unicode-520-ci.  Both failed.  I have always used these in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Use lower() function to convert to lower case in case there are any caps.
use trim() to remove any leading or trailing spaces

```
UPDATE account SET accountPassword='newpassword' WHERE lower(trim(accountEmail))='name@email.com'
```

Comment: Same result.  However the name@email.com is an exact match for the data.  It is all lower and there are no trailing spaces.

Comment: check with a select statement like select * from account WHERE lower(trim(accountEmail))='name@email.com'  and see if it returns any results